# What is the branching factor of BTreeMap and BTreeSet?

Tags: rust, containers

I'm not sure if this is a newbie question.

The rust standard library `std::collections` provides B-tree implementation of map and set.

I have taken a look at the documentation [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html), but I could not find the branching factor *m* used for the implementations.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Does it mean *m* is platform-dependent and not customizable?

Comment: @SvenMarnach Okay, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The B-tree implementations use a [compile-time constant for the number B, which is current set to 6](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/643a79af3d5a31fa87c8a4c9d7f8bc4ebe2add4b/library/alloc/src/collections/btree/node.rs#L43). This means each internal node has between 6 and 11 children.

The specific number is not part of the interface specification – it's considered an implementation detail. The only way to modify the number is to change it in the source code of the alloc crate.